# Get values from dynamic spinners

Tags: android, spinner

I am creating spinners dynamically when i click add button.but i dont know how to get the values from created dynamic spinners.I need to get values how many shirt selected, saree selected and jeans selected when i click a submit button

[image]

this is my code

```
 buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
  container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
  final List<String> dressArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
  dressArray.add("Select Dress");
  dressArray.add("Shirt");
  dressArray.add("Saree");
  dressArray.add("Jeans");

  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
      this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dressArray);

  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  Spinner dress = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dress);
  dress.setAdapter(adapter);


  final List<String> dresscountArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
  dresscountArray.add("Count");
  dresscountArray.add("1");
  dresscountArray.add("2");

  dresscountArray.add("3");


  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
      this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dresscountArray);

  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  Spinner dresscount = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dresscount);
  dresscount.setAdapter(adapter1);
  buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
      (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);


    Spinner dresscount = (Spinner)addView.findViewById(R.id.dresscount);
    Spinner dress = (Spinner)addView.findViewById(R.id.dress);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
              PickupOrder.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dressArray);

          adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          dress.setAdapter(adapter);


          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                  PickupOrder.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dresscountArray);

              adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
              dresscount.setAdapter(adapter1);



    Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
    buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
     }});

    container.addView(addView);
   }});
```

Comment: when want to get values from Spinner ?

Comment: when i click a submit button.i forgot to mention that.sorry

Comment: @ VibinReji Y : see my answer probably help

Answer (score 2):

Firstly define globally

```
String value1;
int value_position1;
```

And then call these methods inside `onCreate` after setting value in each `Spinner`

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                    value_position1 = position;
                    value1 = parent.getSelectedItem().toString()
                            .trim();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
```

And when you call your submit button, use values of each `String`.

Comment: i need to get  all spinners value which is created dynamically by click a submit button

Comment: Create methods for each spinner.

Comment: What do you want now? Nobody is gonna give you each step. Just change according to you. Accept answer if you think it helps you.

Comment: I dont want each step.ineed to get values dynamically created spinners value.when i click add button spinner count also will increase.One user may use 3 spinner and other user may use 5 spinner.anyway thanks for your help

Comment: Then create integer variable globally and initialize it with zero. And put `count++;` in each method as I posted above. It'll tell you how many values are selected. Btw you're asking different question now in the same question. You should accept my answer and post new question for further queries.

Comment: i clearly mentioned "creating spinners dynamically when i click add button" so spinners count will be unknown.you understand my question wrongly.i cannot accept answer.i didnt get what i want

Comment: Coz your English is worst, you don't know yourself what you want.

Comment: Go to hell...nobody needs your response

Answer (score 0):

```
         showallPrompt = "";

                int Count = new_container.getChildCount();
                try {
                    for (int cc = 0; cc < Count; cc++) {
              View child = new_container.getChildAt(cc);
  Spinner value = (Spinner)(child.findViewById(R.id.sp_dynamic));
             String spin_value = value.getSelectedItem().toString();
  showallPrompt += spin_value;

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                         showallPrompt,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
    }



  Do like this on your button click...
```